# Matriz con números aleatorios en C#

Tags: c#, matriz

****Buen día,

Tengo la siguiente duda:

¿Cómo puedo identificar por pantalla que número predomina más?

Por medio de una matriz género números aleatorios, solo el 0 y 1, pero necesito saber cuál de los dos sale en mayor cantidad para mandar un mensaje en pantalla.

Por ejemplo si salen más 1 que 0, que se indique que la matriz tiene más 1 que 0, dependiendo el caso.

Código:****

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace EA_U3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Matriz de:");
            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Matriz por:");
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[,] bidimencion;
            bidimencion = new int[a, b];

            Random numero = new Random();

            // Llenando de la matriz con numero aleatorios entre 0 y 1
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < b; j++)
                {

                    bidimencion[i, j] = numero.Next(0, 2);

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nImpresion de la matriz");

            // Impresion de la matriz
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(bidimencion[i, j]);
                    if (j + 1 == b) 
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine(); 
                    } else 
                    { 
                        Console.Write(" - "); 
                    }

                }

                }
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Estas son las salidas del código**

[image: Salida]

**Espero me puedan orientar,
Saludos**

Comment: Si vuelves a recorrer la matriz contando los 0, y sabiendo la dimensión de la matriz, puedes calcular cual es el que más se repite.

Answer (score 1):

Veamos a ver si te sirve

```
//creamos un método para contar los valores del array que recibe el array por parámetro
static int[] metodoContarValores(int[,] bidimension)
    {
        //creamos un nuevo array para contener el valor de los contadores
        int[] valores = new int[2];
        //creamos dos contadores, uno para los ceros y otro para los unos
        int contador0 = 0, contador1 = 0;

        //creamos dos bucles para recorrer el array, utilizamos el método .GetLength que nos dice el número de valores en filas (0) y columnas (1)
        for (int i = 0; i < bidimension.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bidimension.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //evaluamos que el contenido del array en la posición de iteración sea 0, empleamos el método .equals
                if (bidimension[i,j].Equals(0))
                {
                    //si es cero aumentamos la variable en 1
                    contador0++;
                }
                //si no es cero y es uno
                else if (bidimension[i,j].Equals(1))
                {
                    //aumentamos la variable de unos en uno
                    contador1++;
                }
            }
        }
        //almacenamos los valores de los contadores en el array
        valores[0] = contador0;
        valores[1] = contador1;
        //retornamos el array
        return valores;
    }
```

En el método Main, agregamos:

```
//creamos un array que recibe el resultado del conteo al llamar al método de contar los valores contenidos en el array. Enviamos el array por parámetro
int[] valores = metodoContarValores(bidimencion);
//imprimimos el número de ceros y unos que tiene el array
Console.WriteLine("El array tiene " + valores[0] + " ceros y " + valores[1] + " unos");

//ahora evaluamos el resultado:
//si hay más ceros que unos
if (valores[0] > valores[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine("El array tiene más ceros que unos");
}
//si tiene el mismo número de ceros que de unos
else if (valores[0] == valores[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine("El array tiene el mismo número de ceros que de unos");
}
//si tiene más unos que cero
else if (valores[0] < valores[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine("El array tiene más unos que ceros");
}
```